# Handling exceptions when working with classes

Tags: class, powershell, error-handling, exception, powershell-5.0

What options are available for handling exceptions from class methods?

i.e. with advanced functions we can do this:

```
function Test-Error {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    throw "Error!" 
}

"1. Error's about to happen"
Test-Error -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
"1. Error just happenned (you didn't see it)"

"2. Error's about to happen"
Test-Error -ErrorAction Stop
"2. Error just happened (you saw it; but you won't see this)"
```

To get the same behaviour when calling a class method, I could do this:

```
class ErrorTest
{
    ErrorTest(){}
    TestError(){ throw "Error!" }
}
[ErrorTest]$e = [ErrorTest]::new()


"1. Error's about to happen"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$e.TestError() 
"1. Error just happened (you didn't see it)"

"2. Error's about to happen"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$e.TestError() 
"2. Error just happened (you saw it; but you won't see this)"
```

However I don't like changing `ErrorActionPreference`.  Is there a better solution / a standard way of dealing with such scenarios?

---

### Update

Per TheIncorrigible1's comment, also tried using this method of throwing exceptions:

```
function Test-Error {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    $badObject = 'whatever object caused the issue'
    $actualException = [System.NotSupportedException]::new('I take exception to your use of this function')
    $errorRecord = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new($actualException, 'ExampleException1', [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidData, $badObject)
    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($errorRecord) 
}
```

Comment: If you throw a terminating error, it will be an exception regardless of your error preference.  I'd suggest creating an `[ErrorRecord]` object and utilizing `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1; hadn't come across that way of throwing exceptions before.  Have now discovered this related post: https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/issues/37.